# Android: loading more images in imageview on swipe

Tags: android, android-imageview

I need to show images stored in the internal memory in a single imageview on swipe. i.e on swipe the imageview will show the next image continuously and fast as a wheel. Please tell me some idea to load many images without memory out of range exception and to load fast.

Thank you.

Comment: check out https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: i think of something which s exactly opposite to what u have told me to refer. i need to load pictures faslty.

Comment: provide me some steps to achieve